# Port Mirror and 802.1Q

Tags: cisco, ethernet, 802.1, port-mirroring

Does a port mirror send ethernet frames out of the switch-port with the 802.1Q header bytes still on the frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, no.  However, the behavior can be controlled on the `monitor` command; the `encapsulation` argument controls this.  `replicate` will preserve the encapsulation type that the packet had in transit, while `dot1q` will force the 802.1Q header.